# How to preserve new lines and white space in a particular td in XML using XSL

Tags: css, xml, xslt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulQRB.jpg)I am trying to preserve new lines and white space only for a  particular td which has an random id in XML using XSL

so basically i wanted to preserver new lines inside td which has some large text as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href=new.xsl'?>
  <document>
    <div>
      <table width="100%" border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Data Source</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>123123</td>
            <td>03/20/2018 04:49:40 PM MST</td>
            <td>Test Source</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="random_id_notes" colspan="3">Patient Information Name: Test, FIRST NAME Age: 108 Years DOB: 01/11/1911 Sex: Female First Para# Him boisterous invitation dispatched had connection inhabiting projection. By mutual an mr danger garret edward an. Diverted as strictly exertion
              addition no disposal by stanhill. This call wife do so sigh no gate felt. You and abode spite order get. Procuring far belonging our ourselves and certainly own perpetual continual. It elsewhere of sometimes or my certainty. Lain no as five
              or at high. Everything travelling set how law literature. Sec para# But why smiling man her imagine married. Chiefly can man her out believe manners cottage colonel unknown. Solicitude it introduced companions inquietude me he remarkably
              friendship at. My almost or horses period. Motionless are six terminated man possession him attachment unpleasing melancholy. Sir smile arose one share. No abroad in easily relied an whence lovers temper by. Looked wisdom common he an be
              giving length mr. Good #Third Para Home Call park out she wife face mean. Invitation excellence imprudence understood it continuing to. Ye show done an into. Fifteen winding related may hearted colonel are way studied. County suffer twenty
              or marked no moment in he. Meet shew or said like he. Valley silent cannot things so remain oh to elinor. Far merits season better tended any age hunted.

            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </document>
```

XSL which i tried but it is effecting all the td which i don't want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:n1="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:in="urn:lantana-com:inline-variable-data" xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01" encoding="ISO-8859-1" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"/>
    <xsl:template match="n1:td">
            <span class="content_span">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@styleCode"/>
                  <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            </span>
        </xsl:template>
```

css used

```
 .content_span{
 font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif; 
 display: inline; 
 white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: Can you put some optimized source of your input XML and xslt ?

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using `indent="yes"` if you want to retain whitespace.

In XSLT 3.0 you can override indent="yes" for particular element types, using `suppress-indentation="td"`, but even then you can't do it for particular element instances.

However, I'm not 100% sure this is your problem. In fact, I'm not 100% sure I understand your requirement. Are you wanting the 12 spaces at the start of each line of text in the XML to be visible in the rendered HTML?

Some other comments:

(a) I have no idea what the "n1" namespace prefix is trying to achieve

(b) disable-output-escaping is not magic fairy dust. Don't use it unless you know exactly what it does. In your particular case there is nothing to be escaped and therefore disabling escaping has no effect.

(c) using `mm/dd/yyyy`  dates in XML is going to make your life unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: Thank you for offering your thoughts   1. "n1" is  namespace that been used by company what i actually want to do is in this pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulQRB.jpg

Comment: The text in the image you show seems to bear little relationship to your XML input.

Comment: @VimalTom Following Dr. Kay thoughts, if the image you use for showing your requeriments is from an HTML page, then you will need a [`pre`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-pre-element) element